# How to FREE nested (object type) field classes?

Tags: delphi, oop, rtti

```
TBaseClass = class
public
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;

TFirstClass = class(TBaseClass)
  FMyProp: string;
end;

TSecondClass = class(TBaseClass)
  FMyFirstClass: TFirstClass;
end;
```

I need to implement a DESTRUCTOR that can be able to find all (object type) fields from the
same base class and give a Free on it to avoid all those memory leaks.

Why? Because FMyFirstClass be can created or not, that depends on the flow of my app and I can't garantee when it will be created to Free it, neither do want to fill all destructors with a NIL check kind of code, because i have a lots of fields like that.

I'm trying to use the new RTTI to get all fields based on TBaseClass, but I can't get the instance of the object-field and I'm out of ideas.

Am I going to the right way? What you suggest to do?

Comment: Can you add a small ('pseudo'-) code example of the steps which would result in a memory leak? I see a possible leak by repeated create-and-assign-to-FMyFirstClass, this could be prevented using a setter method which frees the field before assigning the new value

Comment: Why would you want to free object fields that are created in the descendant, within the ancestor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `Free` has no effect on a nil instance. It's deliberately designed that way. Your destructors should call `Free` on any fields of object types which it logically owns, irrelevant of whether the object has been constructed or not.

Comment: Barry, thanks for your answer, but maybe you didn't understand what I tried to say. I have many object-type fields on TSecondClass and i want to implement that crazy destructor on TBaseClass to Free all child fields without doing it manually.

Comment: I know that doesn't matter to call Free on a NIL instance, but in base class I don't know which fields were created on child classes, right? That's what I wanna do on that TBaseClass.Destroy.

Comment: follow the same rule for all the classes and everything will be destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

Delphi objects should always be "Owned" by an other object, and the owner object is responsible for freeing the owned object when it's Destructor is called. Since this is done for each and every class, there shouldn't be any problems. You could use RTTI for this, but it'd be a waist of time and resource, since writing Destructors is so easy.

Example, base class introduces two TObject-type fields:

```
TBaseClass = class
private
public
  OwnedObject: TObject;
  NotOwnedObject: TObject;

  destructor Destroy;override;
end;

destructor TBaseClass.Destroy;override;
begin
  OwnedObject.Free; // TBaseClass owns this object, it should be destroyed when
                   // TBaseClass is destroyed.
  // Do NOT call NotOwnedObject.Free: that object is not owned by TBaseClass,
  // a different object is responsible for calling Free on it.

  // ALWAYS call "inherited" from your destructor, it allows daisy-chaining destructors.
  // more on this in the next example.
  inherited;
end;
```

Descendant classes that introduce new fields should override the destructor and free those objects, then call `inherited` to give the parent a chance to free the objects it introduced. Example:

```
TFirstClass = class(TBaseClass)
public
  AnOtherOwnedObject: TObject;
  AnOtherNotOwnedObject: TObject;

  destructor Destroy;override;
end;

destructor TFirstClass.Destroy;override;
begin
  // Free the stuff we owned and *we* introduced:
  AnOtherOwnedObject.Free;

  // Call the inherited destructor so the base class can free fields they introduced:
  inherited;
end;
```

In your question you say:

> I need to implement a DESTRUCTOR that can be able to find all (object type) fields from the same base class and give a Free on it to avoid all those memory leaks.

As you can see, that's not the way to do it: The derived class's destructor calls `inherited` so the base class gets it's chance to free the fields it introduced.

- As Barry Kelly says, you don't need to check for `nil` before calling `.Free`, because Free does that itself.
- As David Heffernan says, all you need to do is follow this pattern everywhere and you'll be fine, no memory leaks. This is how the VCL always worked!
- As mjn says, pay attention not to override owned objects with other objects without freeing them: when you do that you lose the last reference to the old object and you can't free it any more, it's a guaranteed memory leak.

Comment: +1 for **inherited**. It looks like that's the part the OP is missing.

Comment: Your justification is just copy of what another people posted, why repeat? The OP will read all messages, not only your.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are going the right way. Just free the objects in the class you declare/create them. And as Barry said, you don't need to have nil checks.

Answer (score 1):

The advice you have received in the other answers is correct.  Make sure that you pair up each object instantiation with a corresponding `Free` in the destructor.

I'd like to point out why you can't use RTTI to look up all the object instances and free them.  Some of the object instances may not be owned by the object that is being destroyed.  If you have a field containing a reference to an object that is owned by some other entity in your system, then you are not at liberty to destroy it.  RTTI cannot tell you who owns the object, only you can know that.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it in the wrong way. You have to save the reference to know what you have to free, if you don't know the flow, then your design is fault.

If your needs is something unusual, you can refactory the base class to hold all references, check if this code can help you:

```
program BaseFree;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes, SysUtils;

type
  TBase = class(TObject)
  strict private
    class var Instances: TList;
    class var Destroying: boolean;
    class procedure Clear(Instance: TBase);
  private
    class procedure Debug;
  protected
    class constructor Create;
    class destructor Destroy;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TItem = class(TBase)

  end;

{ TBase }

class procedure TBase.Clear(Instance: TBase);
var
  I: Integer;
  Item: TBase;
begin
  for I := 0 to TBase.Instances.Count -1 do
  begin
    Item:= TBase.Instances[I];
    if Item <> Instance then
      Item.Destroy;
  end;
  TBase.Instances.Clear;
end;

class constructor TBase.Create;
begin
  TBase.Instances:= TList.Create;
end;

constructor TBase.Create;
begin
  if TBase.Destroying then
    // instead of raise Exception, you can "wait" and start a new cycle.
    raise Exception.Create('Cannot Create new instances while Destrying.');

  inherited Create;
  TBase.Instances.Add(Self);
end;

class procedure TBase.Debug;
begin
  Writeln('TBase.Instances.Count: ', TBase.Instances.Count);
end;

destructor TBase.Destroy;
begin
  if not TBase.Destroying then
  begin
    TBase.Destroying:= True;
    try
      TBase.Clear(Self);
    finally
      TBase.Destroying:= False;
    end;
  end;

  inherited;
end;

class destructor TBase.Destroy;
begin
  TBase.Clear(nil);
  TBase.Instances.Free;
end;

procedure CreateItems(Count: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
  Item: TItem;
begin
  TBase.Debug;
  for I := 0 to Count -1 do
    TItem.Create;
  TBase.Debug;
  Item:= TItem.Create;
  TBase.Debug;
  Item.Free;
  TBase.Debug;
end;

begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown:= True;
  try
    CreateItems(100);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Writeln('Press <ENTER> to finish.');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: This is technically a memory leak, and worst it MASKS the memory leak as far as the memory manager is concerned. Leaked memory is memory that gets allocated but only gets freed when the application terminates, and that's what this promotes: the `TBase`'s class destructor only gets called once when the application terminates. Might as well not do anything (ie: let the memory officially "leak") since 0.01 seconds later all memory allocated to the process will be reclaimed by Windows.

Comment: You're providing a ball of code with the designation `"If your needs is something unusual"` without explaining what the unusual thing is. I personally don't think the OP needs something unusual, I think the OP needs to learn to learn to handle memory the proper way, or switch to a GC language.

Comment: My answer was clear, do not implement in this way, and then I provide a code to show how to implement if he wants.

It do not masks memory leak and the code works fine, seems to me that you flag as -1 coz the OP select my answer as correct first.

Comment: The implementation of an business application is the usual, frameworks, garbage collector is unusual. As I stated, for a common application he was tring to do in the wrong way. I do not need to repeat what someone already posted, just read the messages and use mine as a complement.

Comment: You implemented a way to destroy all objects of a given type *when the application terminates*. What problem does that solve? How's that solving the Memory Leak problem? What's the "unusual need" fulfilled using your solution? What makes you think the OP has "special needs"? And you're also wrong about the garbage collector: I said "switch to a GC language", not implement a GC. GC languages include everything `.net` and `Java`: there are countless applications written for those languages (including business app), and you never need to think about freeing memory if you use one of those.

Comment: It just show a way to implement what the OP asks, is up to him follow the aswer to not implement, or use the code as a base to implement it. If you dont like my code it is ok, but there is nothing wrong with the code. I know the needs of the OP coz he is my co worker.

Comment: @CosminPrund let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1125/discussion-between-cesar-romero-and-cosmin-prund)